# Read Azure Key vault secret from on premisis SSIS package

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-sql-database, azure-keyvault, azure-sql-server

I have my database connection string stored in Azure Key Vault as a secret. My SSIS package which is on-premises needs to read connection string from Azure Key Vault.

Usually, when I configure my SSIS package, I configure my connection string at development time and wondering how I can connect Azure Key Vault and consume a secret.

Comment: Which ssis task did you use?

Comment: We used Execute SQL task and Data Flow.

Comment: I'm afraid I we can't, no operations provided for us.

Comment: So what are the options for on-premises SSIS package to read secret from Azure Key Vault ?

Comment: Execute SQL task create the connection to Azure SQL, we need type the password.

Comment: My SQL server is on-premises and I am running SSIS package also from that on-premises server. We have only set up Azure Key Vault on the cloud. Currently, I need to read connection string runtime from the cloud (Key Vault).     I have one option if I run my SSIS package in Azure Data Factory then I can read the connection string from Key Vault, but as organization wise, we are not ready to move our entire SSIS package to Azure Data Factory.

Comment: As I know about Key Vault, it always used in code level.

Comment: Hi @SoftLover, did you get any progresses?

Answer (score 0):

We can connect to Azure key vault from SSIS using ZappySys(Rest API Task).

Need to have below  Azure key vault related information.

App registration name
Client ID
App Client Secret
Redirect URI
SecretName
subscription

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).